# Unable to read correctly from socket

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I have a server application which sends some **xor encrypted strings**. I am reading them from my QT client application. Sometimes, the server is slower and I am not able to receive the entire string. I have tried something like below but it gets stuck ( see the comment below). How can I wait until I have the entire data.  I tried `bytesAviable()` but then again i get stuck (infinite loop)

```
QTcpSocket * sock = static_cast<QTcpSocket*>(this->sender());
if (key == 0)
{
    QString recv(sock->readLine());
    key = recv.toInt();
    qDebug() << "Cheia este " << key;

    char * response = enc_dec("#AUTH|admin|admin",strlen("#AUTH|admin|admin"),key);
    sock->write(response);
}
else
{
    busy = true;
    while (sock->bytesAvailable() > 0)
    {
        unsigned short word;
        sock->read((char*)(&word),2);
        qDebug()<<word;
        //Sleep(100); if i do this than it works great!
        QByteArray bts = sock->read(word);
        while (bts.length() < word)
        {
            char bit; //here get's stuck
            if (sock->read(&bit,1) > 0)
                bts.append(bit);
            sock->flush();
        }

        char * decodat = enc_dec((char*)bts.data(),bts.length() - 2,key);
        qDebug() << decodat;
    }

}
```

Comment: you may want to use waitForReadyRead(). that will return true if the incoming bytes are ready to be read.

Comment: @LwinHtooKo i can't specify how manny bytes i want

Comment: but when you do readAll(), it will give you all bytes (QByteArray). QByteArray.size() is how much bytes it actually reads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I offer you to do the following:

```
QObject::connect(this->m_TCPSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(processRecivedDatagrams()));
```

**Some explanation:**

1. It is convinient to create a class instance of which will manage network;
2. One has the member which is pointer on TCPSocket;
3. In constructor implement connection of signal from socket `readyRead()` which is emmited when needed data was delivered with `SLOT(processRecivedDatagrams())`. which is responsible for processing recived datagrams/ in this case it is processRecivedDatagrams(), also implement this slot

Mind that class which manages network has to inherit from QObject and also in it`s declaration include macros`Q_OBject` for MOC.

update:

i also offer you to **store recived data in container like stack or queue** this will allow you to synhronize sender and reciver (**container in this case acts like buffer**)

```
// SLOT:


void Network::processRecivedDatagrams(void)
{
    if (!this->m_flagLocked) // use analog of mutex 
    {
        this->m_flagLocked = true; // lock resource

    QByteArray datagram;
    do 
    {
        datagram.resize(m_TCPSocket->pendingDatagramSize());
        m_TCPSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());
    }
            Qt::String YourString; // actualy I don`t remember how to declare Qt string
    while (m_TCPSocket->hasPendingDatagrams());
    QDataStream in (&datagram, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

        in  >> YourString



        --numberOfDatagrams;
    }

    this->m_flagLocked = false; // unlock resource
}
```

}

Comment: i have something like this the function i have posted is your equivalent to processReceivedDatagrams

Comment: OK, I think I should give more detailed explanation of function which parse data(see update of my answer). One question: you said that "server application which sends some xor encrypted strings" why if it sends strings you get data using byte??

Comment: If they are xored then a 0 could slip in that string and i will get only a part of the string

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the meaning of `key == 0` is, but you are almost certainly misusing `available()`, like almost everybody else who has ever called it, including me. It tells you how much data can be read *without blocking*. It has nothing to do with how much data may eventually be delivered down the connection, and the reason is that there are TCP APIs that can tell you the former, but not the latter. Indeed the latter doesn't have any real meaning, considering that the peer could keep writing from now until Doomsday. You should just block and loop until you have read the amount of data you need for the next piece of work.

Comment: I try that in the loop to read one byte until i get the bytes that i need but read always return 0. If i sleep is ok!

Comment: @opc0de No, why sleep at all? Just block. read() will do that for you.

Comment: well not exactly read() returns 0 bytes if it has no data to read is not blocking

Comment: @opc0de No it doesn't. read() returns zero at EOS. If you are in non-blocking mode, which you didn't mention above, and there's no data, it will return -1 with errno set to EGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK, depending on your platform. And if you're in non-blocking mode you should be calling select() to tell you when data is available.